# How do I get the unique number of days in a datetime column in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column full of datetime values in a Google Spreadsheet.

I want to get a count of how many **unique days** there are. As in 8pm and 7pm today would count as 1. Tomorrow at 9pm, 3pm and 4pm would also count as 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in A1:A30, the following array formula worked for me:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE(TEXT(A1:A30,"yyyymmdd")))
```